# upgradeProxy doesn’t works

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, proxy-contracts

I have a strange problem. When I want to upgrade my contract (OpenZeppelin upgradeable), I face this error `"Ownable: the caller is not the owner"`, but the owner is the same as in my init function.

I want to update through the but proxy, I encounter this error, everything is fine and working in the testnets, but in the mainnet, I have the following error:

```
'execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0xc9d1562f9EE4A38Db44Bc50623E06Ee5b89adE7b',
    to: '0xd78B285D3DfCa10b7b637E6DC2FBc3638410cd80',
    data: '0x99a88ec400000000000000000000000056c383653f9f646a31f250bb9a86b6dbe3b470070000000000000000000000007b3f857512c57270d3020a9dc8cf6881243b50ca',
    accessList: null
  },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: need more info, such as the proxy implementation address. looks like there was a transfer ownership transaction on this to your 0xc9d1562f9EE4A38Db44Bc50623E06Ee5b89adE7b wallet does that mean you got it solved?

Comment: I've found the issue ,that's comes from owner of admin proxy